# PHP Jira Service Desk REST API

Tags: php, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am struggling to create a request on Jira Service Desk in PHP.

My code is :

```
public function reportIssue(Request $request) { 

    //post
    //authenticate to Jira ...
    //create request ...
    //response ....
    //do something afterwards ... post ...

    $jdata = json_encode($request);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(

        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => SERVICE_DESK_URL . '/rest/servicedeskapi/request/' . $request,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => SERVICE_USERNAME . ':' . SERVICE_PASSWORD,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jdata,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result);
}
```

I am getting empty response body, still like something is wrong.

Pardon me if my mistake is obvious.

Comment: What server-side error/log do you get?

Comment: 404 null error is the server error.

Comment: 404 means "not found", check your CURLOPT_URL option, output it and add the string to your explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Here is my working curl config:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, SERVICE_DESK_URL . '/rest/servicedeskapi/request/' . $request);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, SERVICE_USERNAME . ':' . SERVICE_PASSWORD);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            'X-ExperimentalApi: opt-in'
        )
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($jdata));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```